# Components re-render whenever I type something but I want re-render only after onClick of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, single-page-application

Currently, I'm working on a REACT application that takes two names, gives a percent, and then displays a poem based on that percent. The first submit gathers information and shows what is expected (the percent and poem). After that though, once I start typing in the input fields, LovePercentContent and LovePoem keep re-rendering. Note: the poem being rendered is picked randomly from an array. So the biggest issue is the poem keeps updating as you type into the input fields. I'm still pretty new to React and read through the handle events documentation. But I still seem to be having issues.

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Below is what I've tried so far.

<button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={() => handleSubmit(e)}>
<button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={() => handleSubmit}>

Live version of the App
https://love-poem-calculator.netlify.app/

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import LovePercentContent from "../LovePercentContent/LovePercentContent";
import LovePoem from "../LovePoem/LovePoem";

const LovePercent = () => {
    const [yourName, setYourName] = useState("");
    const [yourCrushName, setYourCrushName] = useState("");
    const [yourLovePercent, setYourLovePercent] = useState("");
    const [yourLovePoems, setYourLovePoems] = useState("");
    const [yourSwitch, setYourSwitch] = useState(false);
    const [yourNameMissing, setYourNameMissing] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (yourName !== "" && yourCrushName !== "") {
            let calcQueryURL =
                "https://love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com/getPercentage?fname=" +
                yourName +
                "&sname=" +
                yourCrushName;
            console.log("yourName2", yourName);
            getLovePercent(calcQueryURL);
            setYourName("");
            setYourCrushName("");
        } else {
            console.log("you most enter two names");
            setYourNameMissing("please enter both names");
        }
    };

    const getLovePercent = (url) => {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_PERCENT_API_KEY,
                "x-rapidapi-host": "love-calculator.p.rapidapi.com",
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                poemLines(data);
                return setYourLovePercent(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    };

    function poemLines(data) {
        let percent = data.percentage;
        let url = `https://poetrydb.org/linecount/${percent}`;
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                return setYourLovePoems(data);
            })
            .then(() => {
                return setYourSwitch(true);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

    if (yourSwitch) {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Enter Two Names:</h2>
                <input
                    name="yourName"
                    value={yourName}
                    placeholder="Your Name"
                    onChange={(e) => setYourName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input
                    name="yourCrushName"
                    value={yourCrushName}
                    placeholder="Your Crush's Name"
                    onChange={(e) => setYourCrushName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Get Poem
                </button>
                <LovePercentContent data={yourLovePercent} />
                <LovePoem data={yourLovePoems} />
            </>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Enter Two Names:</h2>
            <input
                name="yourName"
                value={yourName}
                placeholder="Your Name"
                onChange={(e) => setYourName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
                name="yourName"
                value={yourCrushName}
                placeholder="Your Crush's Name"
                onChange={(e) => setYourCrushName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Get Poem
            </button>
            {yourNameMissing}
        </>
    );
};

export default LovePercent;
```

Comment: What error did you get after loading for a while?

Comment: @SulemanAhmad I'm not receiving an error. The poem just keeps re-rendering every time I type in the input field. I have updated my original post with more information.

Comment: So you want to get poems only when you click on button. right?

Comment: @SulemanAhmad that is exactly what I am looking for. Note: thanks for the title suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a boolean state like

```
const [dataBool, setDataBool]=useState(false);
```

and set this `true` when you click on the button by creating a function or as you like. After that add condition while displaying the `poem data` to screen. If this boolean is true then return poems else not. Like this:

```
   e.g. {dataBool ? showPoems : notShowPoems}
```

This way it will only show when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

### I would say that behaviour is normal to Reactjs and you should not worry about it too much

---

- What you meant by `reloading` is actually `re-rendering` to be exact.
- Every time a state changes (`yourName` and `yourCrushName` in your case) will cause Reactjs to re-render the whole component.

**It's totally fine and it's actually how Reactjs works**.

**Re-rendering is not bad, only updating DOM is worth considerable, and re-rendering does not mean DOM is updated since Reactjs has applied [Virtual Dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) mechanism**

If you don't want your component to re-render consider using [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The only issue is the poem being rendered is picked randomly from an array. So the biggest issue is the poem keeps updating as you type into the input fields. Ill give red a try and see how that goes. Note: I updated my post to add in the poem array part.